# How to make images float using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, image, css, jsp

am pretty new to this angularjs and stuff. but I have seen a few websites in which images move very beautifully. I want to implement that in my website. can anyone help me out how to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you did yet. Can you show your code?

Comment: If you use image slider on your code please refer the following url                                               http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-slide-show-plugin-angularjs/                                                              for further details

Comment: @Seeni Vasan i think that page is interesting... i will try that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use **ng-material-floating-button**

(https://github.com/nobitagit/ng-material-floating-button)

That will likely do the trick.